# Installing Firefox 15  and remove previous version (ubuntu 12.04) 

Tags: installation

Hello I am new in Linux so please forgive my question:

I would like to know how can I update Firefox 14 to Firefox 15 and how to remove the previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have the 12.04 version (Please add that to your question) since it started with Version 14 of Firefox. If you update your **Update Manager** you should see an update for Firefox 15.

After installing Firefox 15, it will automatically upgrade Firefox 14 so there is no need to uninstall it.

[image]

Just an FYI, every time a new version of Firefox comes out, Ubuntu will update to it after a couple of days. This is done automatically and it will show in the Update Manager when it is officially supported in your Ubuntu version. Does not matter the language Firefox is on.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

that will automatically upgrade your Firefox.